# Group structure on module extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra

I'm looking for the proof of the fact that Baer sum give group structure on set of extensions of module $A$ by module $B$. The only proof I know (from Weibel's book) uses an isomorphism with $Ext^1(A,B)$. I was wondering if there is any proof which does not involve derived functors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such proof is in: S.MacLane, Homology, 1963, Theorem III.2.1.